# how do i include BSP library in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, bsp

im trying to compile c++ parellel program using BSPlib , on a platfrom that has bsp compile ( bsp++). Nevertheless , it doesnt seem to recognize any of the bsp functions.

what should i do in order to include / import/ tell the compiler that im using bsp?

include bsplib? bsplib.h ?

thanks

Comment: Have you ever used another C++ library or is it just bsp that causes a problem?

Comment: What environment are you building with? Makefiles, Visual Studio? With any library you need to tell your compiler to link against the library. The specifics of this will be environment dependent. Please modify your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "bsplib.h"
```

then add bsplib to the link library list.

Comment: actully its bsp.h , but thanks that got me to find the answer.