# BSP compiling at windows

Tags: windows, compilation, bsp

i am new here, and in some way, i am newbie in computer world,
and sorry for my bad English. 
we have an a task in our university,i study computer science,
we need to write a code in BSP:
Bulk Synchronous Parallel.
i love to work at windows environment, so i want to compile this libraries at windows.
i found the website that i can download a source code, and some other version
to compile it at windows. 
in the start i try to compile it with MINGW with it gcc,
but it not help, it has many error.
i try to compile it with the version of windows,

need to install a perl first, so i install the latest perl -> strawberry perl.
when i run the bat script, it say the file not found and point to driver U that
i don't have.
so what i basicly ask to someone help me to compile this libraries at windows,
and send me zip to my mail, or tell me how to fix all the error i have
when i compile it. it not only for me, it for all the student that want
to work at windows environment, and for other generations of students that take that course
in my university.

BSP site:

//http://www.bsp-worldwide.org/implmnts/oxtool/

version of source code of BSP:

//http://www.bsp-worldwide.org/BSPlib/v1.4_bsplib_toolset.tar.gz

version for windows:

//ftp://ftp.comlab.ox.ac.uk/pub/Packages/BSP/v1.4_bsplib_distribution_NT4.0.zip

perl site:

//http://strawberryperl.com/

thank you for all your help :]
Tal.

Comment: Get in touch with your class mate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492472/how-do-i-include-bsp-library-in-a-c-program

Comment: i see his question before i write this one,
he ask how to use bspcc, not to creat one.
there is a linux version in our server,
but i want to compile at windows.
even our Teaching Assistants not helping us so much,
so i seek an help here over the net.